# The login on drupal does not work after the transfer of development to live

Tags: drupal, authentication

My drupal website work properly on the live and development.

The development is in the form of: stage.exemple.com and it uses the same database as the live.

I am unable to connect to live once I copied the files from development to live, nor with the admin or a normal user, I get "Access denied You are not authorized to access this page. " As error.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to update $cookie_domain variable in settings.php.